# how to split rows in columns to have a time series

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 3 variables: `userID`, `y` and `timestamp`. `df` is an example.

```
df <- data.frame(userID=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),  
                 y=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.01), 
                 timestamp=as.POSIXct(c("2017-10-01 21:00:00",  
                                        "2017-10-01 22:00:00", 
                                        "2017-10-01 23:00:00", 
                                        "2017-10-02 00:00:00",  
                                        "2017-10-01 21:00:00", 
                                        "2017-10-01 22:00:00", 
                                        "2017-10-01 23:00:00",  
                                        "2017-10-01 22:00:00", 
                                        "2017-10-01 23:00:00", 
                                        "2017-10-02 00:00:00"),  tz="GMT"))
```

I want to split rows by `userID` and join the blocks like columns by the same `timestamp`, like in `df_new`:

```
df_new <- data.frame(as.POSIXct(c("2017-10-01 21:00:00",  
                                  "2017-10-01 22:00:00", 
                                  "2017-10-01 23:00:00", 
                                  "2017-10-02 00:00:00"), tz="GMT"),  
                     c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4), c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7,NA),  
                     c(NA, 0.8, 0.9, 0.01))
colnames(df_new) <- c("timestamp", "1", "2", "3")
```

I tried to use the command `split(df, df$userID)`, but I'm not able to join the columns.

I have a huge dataframe, so I need a solution available on a big dataset.
Can anybody help me, please?

I need to do this trasformation because I have to use the resulting dataframe as multiple hourly time series.

Comment: Just do: `library(tidyverse) df %>% spread(userID, y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `data.table::dcast()` approach, which is very fast.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(df, timestamp ~ userID, value.var=c("y"))
#             timestamp   1   2    3
# 1 2017-10-01 21:00:00 0.1 0.5   NA
# 2 2017-10-01 22:00:00 0.2 0.6 0.80
# 3 2017-10-01 23:00:00 0.3 0.7 0.90
# 4 2017-10-02 00:00:00 0.4  NA 0.01
```